# if else statement logic issues in stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I've multiple `IF...ELSE` statements in my stored procedure, but apparently only 2 at one time can be used?

Stored Procedure:

```
IF  EXISTS(SELECT userid FROM registeredusers WHERE Username = @Username)
  IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT userid FROM registered WHERE Username = @Username and eventname = @b)
  BEGIN
    select 0
    INSERT INTO [registered]
        ([Username]
        ,[CreatedDate]
        ,[eventname])
    VALUES
        (@Username
        ,GETDATE()
        ,@b)
  END
  ELSE IF  NOT EXISTS(SELECT userid FROM registeredusers WHERE Username = @Username)
  BEGIN
    SELECT -1 -- invalid user
  END
  ELSE IF  EXISTS(SELECT userid FROM registered WHERE Username = @Username and eventname = @b)
  BEGIN
    SELECT -2 -- username
  END
```

Pre-post page with 3 different messages using a switch case (only `-2` and `0` is used, `-1` is totally ignored). 
It won't select `-1` if a user doesn't exist.

It just goes to the post over page with the session value, even though it's incorrect.

```
protected void RegisterUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int userId = 0;
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert_User"))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();

                Session["username"] = txtUsername.Text;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString());

                if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(cmd.ExecuteScalar()))
                {
                    userId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                }
            }

            string messages = string.Empty;
            switch (userId)
            {
                case 0:
                    Response.Redirect("userinfo.aspx", false);
                    break;
                    Label2.Text = Convert.ToString(userId);
                case -1:
                    messages = "invalid user";
                    Label2.Text = Convert.ToString(userId);
                    break;
                case -2:
                    messages = "You've already registered!";
                    Label2.Text = Convert.ToString(userId);
                    //Label2.Text = messages;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Posted page's code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["username"]);

    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    using (SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            scmd.Connection = con;
            scmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            scmd.Parameters.Add("@b", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Label1.Text;
            scmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM registered where username = @b";
            con.Open();
        }
    }
}
```

replying to Brendan : 
`select --1 invalid user` isn't being executed, it's being posted over to the next page, which means `case -1` is ignored.

However the first if else statement of the procedure is a little weird, on the database side, it's working fine, it's correctly checking for conditions before inserting the values.

But `case 0` doesn't work, it triggers `case -2` instead.

Variables :
@Username = username 
@b = eventname

registered users column : username, eventname

I'm checking if a user exists within `registeredusers` table and doesn't exist within `registered` hence the 2 if statements together.

Comment: Can you provide a heap more detail?  Which `IF` block in the procedure isn't being executed, and for the given block of code, what are the variables (e.g. `@Username`) and what is the content of the `registeredusers` table?

Comment: added reply to main post so it's easier to see

Answer (score 3):

(only -2 and 0 is used, -1 is totally ignored). It won't select -1 if a user doesn't exist. Reason behind this is the first statement i.e:

```
IF  EXISTS(SELECT userid FROM registeredusers WHERE Username = @Username)
```

in which you are checking the condition if exists then go further. If user does not exists how it will go inside other statement. You can write a else part for that like

```
IF  EXISTS(SELECT userid FROM registeredusers WHERE Username = @Username)
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT userid FROM registered WHERE Username = @Username and eventname = @b)
  BEGIN
   INSERT INTO [registered]
        ([Username]
        ,[CreatedDate]
        ,[eventname])
    VALUES
        (@Username
        ,GETDATE()
        ,@b)
    select 0
  END      
  ELSE IF  EXISTS(SELECT userid FROM registered WHERE Username = @Username and eventname = @b)
  BEGIN
    SELECT -2 -- username
  END
END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    SELECT -1 -- invalid user
  END
```

Comment: Now, case -2 and -1 are used. case 0 is ignored. Database is still being inserted with values properly but doesn't select 0.

Comment: firstly write the insert statement in the IF NOT EXISTS block and then write select statement  like SELECT 0

Comment: Not working still, it's somehow just ignoring select 0, and jumping to -2. (IMO)Feels like it's looping and it will never jump to 0. So like after inserting, it will loop the statement again, overwriting the 0 and goes to -2 (since the user exists now .)

Comment: Can you please write the print statement instead of select and check the output in the output window via executing the store procedure(pass different parameter as per requirement) in database and see why it's happening.

Comment: I tried the same at my end and its working as expected.

Comment: Yes this statement is definitely working, but the select part is not working, I've changed to another alternative to solve this, thanks :)